# c# Thread-safe control DataBindings to a property modified by a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, data-binding, thread-safety, controls, backgroundworker

I am struggling trying to DataBind a TextBox Text to a property that gets modified by a BackgroundWorker.
Here is my code:

This is my BackgroundWorker that's inside a socket server class (this class gets instantiated by my main UI thread):

```
private void clientsConnections_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                clientsConnections.Reset();

                log.logs = "Waiting for a connection...";
                server.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), server);

                clientsConnections.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            log.logs = er.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Here is the class with the property I want to bind to:

```
class eventsLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string log;
    private string lastEntry;

    public string logs
    {
        get { return log; }
        set {   lastEntry = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + value + "\r\n"; 
                log = lastEntry + log;
                OnPropertyChanged("logs");
            }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public string lastlog
    {
        get { return lastEntry; }
    }


}
```

And here is the way i tryed to databind the TextBox Text to that logs property:

```
        Binding bi = textBox2_Output.DataBindings.Add("Text", fServer.log, "logs");
        bi.ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        bi.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never;
```

While running the application, when the log.logs property gets updated by the BackgroundWorker I get a InvaliOperationException that the TextBox control was accessed from a thread other then the thread it was created on..

Sadly in the main UI thread I can't check for InvokReguired, becouse log.logs property its in a class instantiated by the main thread.
The thread unsafe conflict is because log.logs property gets modified by a BackgroundWorker thread, i presumme...?!

I have tried doing it like this also:

```
 Action action = () => textBox2_Output.DataBindings.Add("Text", fServer.log, "logs");
 textBox2_Output.Invoke(action);
```

And:

```
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
           textBox2_Output.DataBindings.Add("Text", fServer.log, "logs");
        });
```

With no luck...

I was thinking of trying to check for InvokRequired inside the property set definition, but i have no ideea how to reference the control from there..

So, what would be the correct way to DataBind a control to a property that gets modified at some point by another thread?

I have tried to find a answer to this but sadly most discussions are held from the point of view of the BackgroundWorker, checking for InvokRequired and then doing the actual invoke or thread safe control call.

Please point me to the right direction to explore a solution for this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That's the limitation of the "Winforms", you can't update the property which is bound to a control in a worker thread. WPF solves this by automatically marshaling the control to UI thread.

We need to do the same in "Winforms", We use `SynchroniazationContext` abstraction provided by .net 2.0 to achieve it.

```
class eventsLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SynchronizationContext context;

    public eventsLog(SynchronizationContext context)
    {
         this.context = context ?? new SynchroniazationContext();
    }

    public string logs
    {
        get { return log; }
        set {   
                lastEntry = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + value + "\r\n"; 
                log = lastEntry + log;
                context.Post(()=> OnPropertyChanged("logs"), null);
                //OnPropertyChanged("logs") will be invoked in UI thread asynchronously
            }
    }
    ...
}
```

When you're creating a new `eventsLog` instance you should pass `SynchroniazationContext.Current` to the constructor and that's it. Your property change notification will be run in main thread.

```
public MainForm()
{
    this.eventsLog = new eventsLog(SynchroniazationContext.Current);
}
```

Read more about [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

**Note:** It is imperative to create instance of `eventsLog` only from UI thread, otherwise `SynchroniazationContext.Current` will be null and hence property change notifications will be raised in "ThreadPool", which means that you'll get an cross thread exception.

Comment: Over 5 years, this is still save me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When the log.logs property is updated by the BackgroundWorker, has the BGW completed or in the middle of other stuff?

If its completed, then you can pass the updated property via the BGW Result and let the RunWorkerCompleted handle updating the form control, since RunWorkerCompleted runs in the same thread as the form UI.

If the BGW is still in middle of some other processing, then you can send an update in a ProgressChanged event in the userState parameter.  The ReportProgress event access the percentProgress as an integer, but that integer does not really have to represent percent progress between 0 - 100.  It might be number of steps, or the integer value could represent a special value to signal updating something back on the form.  And those values can even be negative:

Just spitballing it here:

```
const int UpdateLogLogs = -1;
```

In the BGW you would then have:

```
worker.ReportProgress(UpdateLogLogs, value);
```